# C# - Convert hex string to byte array of hex values

Tags: c#, arrays, hex

This question looks like a bunch of other questions, but none exactly match what I need.  The problem with the other related questions seem to do an implicit conversion to decimal based on Visual Studio's IntelliSense.

Goal: Trying to convert hex string to byte array of hex values (not decimal values) in C#.

```
public static byte[] ConvertHexValueToByteArray() 
{
  string hexIpAddress = "0A010248"; // 10.1.2.72 => "0A010248"
  byte[] bytes = new byte[hexIpAddress.Length / 2];

  for (int i = 0; i < hexIpAddress.Length; i += 2)
  {
    string s2CharSubStr = hexIpAddress.Substring(i, 2);  // holds "0A" on 1st pass, "01" on 2nd pass, etc.

    if ((s2CharSubStr.IsAllDigit()) && (int.Parse(s2CharSubStr) < 10)) // fixes 0 to 9
      bytes[i / 2] = (byte) int.Parse(s2CharSubStr); // same value even if translated to decimal
    else if (s2CharSubStr.IsAllDigit()) // fixes stuff like 72 (decimal) 48 (hex)
      bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(s2CharSubStr, 10); // does not convert, so 48 hex stays 48 hex. But will not handle letters.
    else if (s2CharSubStr[0] == '0') // handles things like 10 (decimal) 0A (hex) 
      bytes[i / 2] = // ?????????????????????????????
    else // handle things like AA to FF (hex)
      bytes[i / 2] = // ?????????????????????????????
   }

   return bytes;
 }
```

Answers like the two below do implicit conversions (as viewed in Visual Studio's IntelliSense) from the hex to decimal AND/OR fail to handle the alpha part of the hex:
1)

```
bytes[i / 2] = (byte)int.Parse(sSubStr, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

2)

```
bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
```

3) 
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexIpAddress.Substring(i, 2));

So I would like the function to return the equivalent of this hard-coded byte array:

```
byte[] currentIpBytes = {0x0A, 01, 02, 0x48};
```

Comment: What is the difference between "decimal" and "hex values"? They are bytes, 0x01 is the same as 1, 0x0a is the same as 10 an so on, when you deal with binary data, not string data, the representation is indifferent of the underlying data.

Comment: But 2) is correct. A `byte` value is a `byte` value...so `bytes[0]` will be of value `10` (decimal) which _is_ `0x0A`. What other value do you want `bytes[0]` to have?

Comment: I would like the function to return the equivalent of this hard-coded byte array:   byte[] currentIpBytes = {0x0A, 01, 02, 48};

Comment: Yes, so `bytes[i/2] = Convert.ToByte(hexIpAddress.Substring(i,2));` does exactly what you want. (though it's `0x48`, not `48`)

Comment: @Rene,         public static byte[] ConvertHexValueToByteArray()
        {
            string hexIpAddress = "0A010248"; 
            byte[] bytes = new byte[hexIpAddress.Length / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < hexIpAddress.Length; i += 2)
            {
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexIpAddress.Substring(i, 2));
            }
            return bytes;
        }      // returns error.   I would be happy at 0x48 in the byte array.

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment I forgot the `, 16)` at `Convert.ToByte`. Hope my answer makes things clear. Btw: in your expected result, the `48` should definitly be `0x48` or `72`, as 0x48 = 72, but not 48.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string hexIpAddress = "0A010248"; // 10.1.2.72 => "0A010248"
byte[] bytes = new byte[hexIpAddress.Length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < hexIpAddress.Length; i += 2)
    bytes[i/2] = Convert.ToByte(hexIpAddress.Substring(i, 2), 16);
```

This results in this array:

```
bytes = {0x0A, 0x01, 0x02, 0x48};
```

or represented as decimals:

```
bytes = {10, 1, 2, 72};
```

or as binaries `00001010`, `000000001`, `00000010`, `01001000` (binary literals are still not supported in C#6).

The *values are the same*, there is no *representation* in any base in `byte`. You can only decide how the values should be represented when converting them to strings again:

```
foreach(byte b in bytes)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {0:X}", b);
```

results in

```
10 A
1 1
2 2
72 48
```

Comment: Correction: "hex" needs to be "hexIpAddress" in your answer.

Comment: Let me understand.  So my core problem I have is a misunderstanding of what code insight shows  {10, 1, 2, 72} it is really the hex values underneath {0x0A, 0x01, 0x02, 0x48} ?    So when I send this to a device that wants my IP address in hex values, it will really be fine?

Comment: @EricWood well that depends on the device and who told you it "expects hex values", but I'm pretty sure it will be alright. Btw: if you're using Visual Studio, you can tell the debugger if it should show the values as hex or decimal (right click in the "Watch" window, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

```
private string DateToHex(DateTime theDate)
{
    string isoDate = theDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

    string resultString = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < isoDate.Length ; i++)    // Amended
    {
        int n = char.ConvertToUtf32(isoDate, i);
        string hs = n.ToString("x");
        resultString += hs;
    }
    return resultString;
}
```