# Convert varbinary to base64 in .NET

Tags: .net, base64

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664937/retrieve-varbinary-value-as-base64-in-mssql) I asked how can I convert `varbinary` to valid BASE64 `string` value in MSSQL.

Now I'd like to know how can it be done **without MSSQL** (in .NET f.e.).

Let's think of a method which accepts the following `string` (or `byte` array)

`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`

and returns valid BASE64

`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`

Comment: Well which are you interested in - converting a hex string, or converting a byte array? Those are two different questions with different answers. (I suspect both have been asked before.) `Convert.ToBase64String` is what you're after, basically. It's not clear why you've tagged this sql-server and varbinary if you need to do it *without* SQL.

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809675 for byte array to base64; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963481 for hex to byte array

Comment: I was not sure what MSSQL returns me. 
LinqPad5 returns me already converted string. 
That's why I included MSSQL tag. It was for completeness of the question.
Thanks for the links!

Comment: "I was not sure what MSSQL returns me." It sounds like you should be able to have checked that before asking the question though, at which point the SQL would have been irrelevant. "LinaPad5 returns me already converted string." What is LinaPad5 and what does it have to do with the question? If you mean LINQPad, you should be able to do research *not* in LINQPad, unless your final code really needs to be running in LINQPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [`Convert.ToBase64String()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: That is correct. `ToBase64String` works.
I was trying with casting to `byte[]` and then encoding with different (`UTF8`, `UTF16`, `ASCII`), but completely forgot about this one.
This answer will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# method `Convert.ToBase64String()` for this. Pass the byte array to this method as parameter and it will return it's base64 string.